# Errors are not being sent to rollbar Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, rollbar

When I throw new `Exception('test exception');` from a class the bug is passed to my rollbar dashboard. But when I cause a Laravel error, something like:

> "syntax error, unexpected '$user' (T_VARIABLE)"

it doesn’t get passed.

I have it working perfectly on another project and it sends all bugs but that is in Laravel 5.0. I then tried Laravel Rollbar by jenssegers, thinking it would be more suited for Laravel 5.1 but that behaves the exact same way, only passing exceptions that I explicitly throw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing any third party packages that would interfere with the Handler class in the exceptions directory. The likes of `filp/whoops` could be catching the exception first.

Comment: Is there a way to get whoops & rollbar to work _together_?